# No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I have some API on Spring Boot. I've added a login mechanism for not having them accessible from everyone.

I have a table Users having username, hashed password and role.

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    private final DatabaseUserDetailsService databaseUserDetailsService;
    
    public SecurityConfiguration(DatabaseUserDetailsService databaseUserDetailsService) {
        super();
        this.databaseUserDetailsService = databaseUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.csrf()
                    .disable()
                    .cors()
                    .disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/registration")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }
      
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
      DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = 
        new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
      provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
      provider.setUserDetailsService(this.databaseUserDetailsService);
      return provider;
    }
      
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    
}
```

On my endpoints I have enabled @CrossOrigin annotation:

```
@CrossOrigin
      @GetMapping("/devices")
      List<Device> findAllDevices() {
            return repository.findAll();
      }
```

I get this error:
[image]

```
"No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http//MyMachineIP' is therefore not allowed access"
```

how can I fix this?

EDIT:

By enabling logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
I get this:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.isAllowed(DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.isAllowed(DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.java:67) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.ErrorPageSecurityFilter.isAllowed(ErrorPageSecurityFilter.java:75) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.ErrorPageSecurityFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageSecurityFilter.java:65) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.ErrorPageSecurityFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageSecurityFilter.java:60) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:87) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:403) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:249) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Tried enabling CORS in Spring Security (.cors(withDefaults())) and providing a CorsConfigurationSource as an @Bean

```
    @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors(withDefaults())
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/registration")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }
    
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:8090"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
}
```

But still getting the error, if it is correct.
But I get this error spring boot side:

```
When allowCredentials is true, allowedOrigins cannot contain the special value "*" since that cannot be set on the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response header. To allow credentials to a set of origins, list them explicitly or consider using "allowedOriginPatterns" instead.
```

Which it does not make sense to me since allowedOrigins does not contains "*". Just for the purpose of trying, I turned it to false, still getting that error.

Comment: Have you tried enabling CORS in Spring Security (`.cors(withDefaults())`) and providing a `CorsConfigurationSource` as an `@Bean`?

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg thank you for the answer, I have edited and tried what you told but still getting the error. In "AllowedOrigins" i should put the url that the error is telling me right?

Comment: Can you share the `CorsConfigurationSource` you're using?

Comment: Also, you now have `.cors(withDefaults())` followed by `.cors().disable()`. So I'm not sure that is quite correct. Try removing `.cors().disable()`.

Comment: My CorsConfigurationSource it's there, also there is no ".cors().disable()" it's ".csrf().disable()"

Comment: Anyway, with this new configuration I no longer get the "Access is denied" but I get ** When allowCredentials is true, allowedOrigins cannot contain the special value "*" ** Why is that? I didnt set * in setAllowedOrigins

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Actually  I had some other code elsewhere that I deleted that gave troubles. Now Access is denied anyway but I managed to configure cors, so make a question and I'll vote you

Comment: Ah, thanks, I had misread and missed some details of your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried enabling CORS in Spring Security (`.cors(withDefaults())`) and providing a `CorsConfigurationSource` as an @Bean?